# Send user token with every request

Tags: angularjs

I am currently writing my first `AngularJS` application.

I've made a login system where the client is providing a user-token every time a `POST` request is sent.

Currently, I have to provide this to every `POST` request I make. Is there a way to make this process automatic?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know angularjs so i had to look this up in the [$http documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

It appears you can set common headers like so:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['user-token'] = xxx;
```

So you could just pass the user token via the headers much like you would cookies. I do this on one of my jquery apps, where i pass the user session token via a header, then in my scripting language (PHP) i grab it using `$_SERVER['X_MYAPPNAME_TOKEN']` and validate it (i actually pass it as `X-Myappname-Token` but PHP transforms it a little

Comment: Yep, default headers is the way to go here.  I do something similar with one of my apps that connects to a 3rd party REST api.

Answer (score 0):

I use Basic Auth

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + encoded;
```